# $|3^a-2^b|\neq p$, from a contest

Tags: prime-numbers, contest-math

I recently came across an old contest problem: (I did not find the solution anywhere)

> > Find the least **prime** number which cannot be written in the form $|3^a-2^b|$ where $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers.

At the beginning I thought that the answer was the number $2$ but the ''nonnegative integers'' allows us to take $a=1$ and $b=0$.
Also we have:
$3=2^2-3^0$
$5=3^2-2^2$
$7=2^3-3^0$
$11=3^3-2^4$
$13=2^4-3^1$
$17=3^4-2^6$
and so on...
Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance

P.S. I am familiar with Pillai's theorem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PillaisTheorem.html
but i would like to see -if possible- a solution much more simple because  it was  a contest problem.

Comment: $19 = 3^3-2^3$.

Comment: Looks like $41$ is first such prime number.

Comment: Yeah, since $23=2^5-3^2$, $29=2^5-3^1$, $31=2^5-3^0$, $37=2^6-3^3$

Comment: @Oleg567 Now remains to be seen elementary/at contest level that $41$ cannot be written as $|3^a-2^b|$ ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One readily finds representations for all primes $<41$.

Assume $41=|3^a-2^b|$ that is $2^b\pm 41=3^a$.

By not finding powers of three among the numbers $2^b\pm41$ with $b\le 2$, we conclude $b\ge 3$.
Then $3^a\equiv \pm41\pmod{8}$, which is equivalent to $a\equiv 0\pmod 2$.
Especially $3^a\equiv1\pmod {8}$ and hence $41=3^a-2^b$.

Likewise, we can check and exclude small values of $a$, hence know that $2^b\equiv -41\pmod{3}$, which is equivalent to $b\equiv 0\pmod 2$.

But then $a$ and $b$ are both even and we obtain a factorization
$41=(3^{a/2}-2^{b/2})(3^{a/2}+2^{b/2})$ and conclude $3^{a/2}+2^{b/2}=41$, $3^{a/2}-2^{b/2}=1$, i.e. $3^{a/2}=\frac{41+1}2$, which is absurd.

Comment: + Clear! Very nice!

Comment: I am sorry but i am confused: what if $2^b\equiv +41\pmod{3}$ ?Whouldn't that mean that b is odd? Everything else looks crystal but how do you reject the case ''+41''?

Comment: @Konstantinos Gaitanas, a row above: $41=3^a-2^b$, hence $2^b=3^a-41$, hence $2^b\equiv -41 (\bmod~3)$. Only.

Comment: @Oleg567 and what if $41=2^b-3^a$?

Comment: @Konstantinos Gaitanas: In general, $3^a$ is $1,3,9,27,81, ...$, hence $3^a\equiv 1$ or $3 (\bmod~8)$. If you consider $41=2^b-3^a$ ($b\ge 3$), then you consider eq. $3^a\equiv -41\equiv 7 (\bmod~8)$.